# How can I mark a table read-only?

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with a migration of a django site, and I'd like make all tables read-only except for the django_session table. How can I do this?

Comment: Revoke write rights from current user or create another user with read only rights.

Answer (score 8):

```
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
FROM public, <target_role>;
```

Possibly add more roles to the list, but do not forget the role `public`.
Possibly add more schemas to the list, but do not forget the schema `public`.
[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-revoke.html)

Superusers (like `postgres`) ignore permissions. A trigger would be an alternative to include them, too.